# Разные маршруты для одной логики, авторизация

Tags: laravel

Есть два маршрута, один из которых за авторизацией, но с одинаковым методом getPDF

```
Route::get('/get_pdf_api', [pdfController::class, 'getPDF'])->middleware('auth:api');
Route::get('/get_pdf', [pdfController::class, 'getPDF']);
```

Как тут сделать так, чтобы не дублировался код в методе getPDF?

```
public function getPDF(Request $request)
{
    $news = New::all();
    $pdf = PDF::loadView('pdftest', ['news' => $news,]);
    return $pdf->download('file.pdf');
}
```

Comment: Какой код? Нам угадать надо что вы делаете в методе getPDF()?

Comment: добавил код метода getPDF

Comment: Не понятно, где тут дублирование

Comment: код getPDF, один маршрут за авторизацией, а другой нет

Answer (score 1):

Вы же понимаете что в вашем коде в принципе нет логики. Какая разница получать одни и те же данные будучи авторизованным или нет.
При чём не важно по апи они или ещё как-то. Пользователю нет смысла пользоваться авторизованным маршрутом, когда есть точно такой же не авторизованный. Ибо данные не отличаются никак.

Отвечая вопрос о "дублировании". Оно здесь только в том, что вы дублируете "одинаковые" маршруты делающие одно и то же.

Когда "такая" ситуация нужна. Представим что мы хотим сделать функционал получения новостей для пользователя и не авторизованного пользователя. С одним отличием, что авторизованный может получать **свои** новости.

**Пример**

Есть страница, где есть две кнопки. Получить новости и получить свои новости. Вторая показывается только когда пользователь авторизован. При клике на кнопку запрос отправляется на сервер по **своему** маршруту, получая новости в том виде в котором хотим. При этом вторая кнопка отправляет параметр для проверки какую кнопку кликнули.

И в коде, в методе `getPDF` может быть следующее (представлен псевдо код):

```
public function getPDF(Request $request)
{
    // где my() это laravel scope 
    $news = auth()->check() && $request->my_news ? New::my()->get() : New::all();

    $pdf = PDF::loadView('pdftest', ['news' => $news,]);
    return $pdf->download('file.pdf');
}
```

Тогда смысл в двух маршрутах с одним методом и разным `middleware` имеет смысл.